# Deploy MEAN app to Heroku blank page

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku, mean-stack

So this is my first MEAN stack app and I'm trying to deploy it to heroku but not having any success.  My app builds locally and successfully on heroku.  When checking the logs I can see my console starting up connected to db.  But the problem is my page is blank.

I've looked at this tutorial [here](https://github.com/gugui3z24/MEAN-Stack-With-Angular-2-Tutorial) and also the heroku docs but I'm not sure how to resolve this blank page?

Any help is greatly appreicated
Thanks